# Get Row Id for a Lightning:ButtonIcon

Tags: lightning, aura-iteration

I am adding a buttonIcon for each aura:iteration record in my interface. I need to get the Id of the row that the button is on.

Here is my component code:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.proformaDetailsIncome}" var="profIncome" indexVar="index">
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Type">
                        <div clas="slds-truncate">
                            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:clear"  size="x-small" name="4" onclick="{!c.deleteRow}" title="Delete Income Record" value="{!index}" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="SubType">
                        <!--<div clas="slds-truncate" title="{#profIncome.SubType__c}">{#profIncome.SubType__c}-->
                            <input type="text" aura:id="iYear1" value="{#profIncome.SubType__c}" class="slds-input" onfocusout="{!c.updateDetailRecord}" data-Index="{!index}" data-Type="iYear" data-attrName="SubType__c"/>
                        <!--</div>-->

                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Year 1">
                        <input type="number" aura:id="iYear1" value="{#profIncome.Yr_1__c}" class="slds-input" onfocusout="{!c.updateDetailRecord}" data-Index="{!index}" data-Type="iYear" data-attrName="Yr_1__c"/>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Year 2">
                        <input type="number" aura:id="iYear2" value="{#profIncome.Yr_2__c}" class="slds-input" onfocusout="{!c.updateDetailRecord}" data-Index="{!index}" data-Type="iYear" data-attrName="Yr_2__c"/>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Year 3">
                        <input type="number" aura:id="iYear3" value="{#profIncome.Yr_3__c}" class="slds-input" onfocusout="{!c.updateDetailRecord}" data-Index="{!index}" data-Type="iYear" data-attrName="Yr_3__c"/>
                    </td>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showYear4}">
                        <td data-label="Year 4">
                            <input type="number" aura:id="iYear4" value="{#profIncome.Yr_4__c}" class="slds-input" onfocusout="{!c.updateDetailRecord}" data-Index="{!index}" data-Type="iYear" data-attrName="Yr_4__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showYear5}">
                        <td data-label="Year 5">
                            <input type="number" aura:id="iYear5" value="{#profIncome.Yr_5__c}" class="slds-input" onfocusout="{!c.updateDetailRecord}" data-Index="{!index}" data-Type="iYear" data-attrName="Yr_5__c"/>
                        </td>
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showYear6}">
                        <td data-label="Year 6">
                            <input type="number" aura:id="iYear6" value="{#profIncome.Yr_6__c}" class="slds-input" onfocusout="{!c.updateDetailRecord}" data-Index="{!index}" data-Type="iYear" data-attrName="Yr_6__c"/>
                        </td>     
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showYear7}">
                        <td data-label="Year 7">
                            <input type="number" aura:id="iYear7" value="{#profIncome.Yr_7__c}" class="slds-input" onfocusout="{!c.updateDetailRecord}" data-Index="{!index}" data-Type="iYear" data-attrName="Yr_7__c"/>
                        </td>     
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showYear8}">
                        <td data-label="Year 8">
                            <input type="number" aura:id="iYear8" value="{#profIncome.Yr_8__c}" class="slds-input" onfocusout="{!c.updateDetailRecord}" data-Index="{!index}" data-Type="iYear" data-attrName="Yr_8__c"/>
                        </td>     
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showYear9}">
                        <td data-label="Year 9">
                            <input type="number" aura:id="iYear9" value="{#profIncome.Yr_9__c}" class="slds-input" onfocusout="{!c.updateDetailRecord}" data-Index="{!index}" data-Type="iYear" data-attrName="Yr_9__c"/>
                        </td>     
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showYear10}">
                        <td data-label="Year 10">
                            <input type="number" aura:id="iYear10" value="{#profIncome.Yr_10__c}" class="slds-input" onfocusout="{!c.updateDetailRecord}" data-Index="{!index}" data-Type="iYear" data-attrName="Yr_10__c"/>
                        </td>     
                    </aura:if>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
```

I have been using the following two options, and neither is returning the requested value:

```
var currentTargetEvent = event.currentTarget;
var currentValue = currentTargetEvent.getAttribute("value");
```

or

```
var currentTargetEvent = event.currentTarget;
var currentValue = currentTargetEvent.value;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target is a component, but you're trying to get an attribute of a DOM element. This won't work, of course. Instead, put the ID up a bit, and you can grab it:

```
<div clas="slds-truncate" data-id="{!profIncome.Id}">
    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:clear"  size="x-small" name="4" onclick="{!c.deleteRow}" title="Delete Income Record" value="{!index}" />
</div>
```

...

```
deleteRow: function(component, event, helper) {
  var recordId = event.target.closest("[data-id]").dataset.id;
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much for that. Still learning a bit.